# Trying to make a magic eight ball and if the user does not enter a question it should say please ask a question but it does not work

Tags: javascript

```
//Magic 8 ball

//Variables
let questionEl = document.getElementById("Question");
let magic8BallEl = document.getElementById("magic8ball");
let answerSpaceEl = document.getElementById("answerSpace");

//eventlistener 
magic8BallEl.addEventListener("click", giveAnswer)

function giveAnswer() {
  if(questionEl === ""){
    document.getElementById("answerSpace").innerHTML = " Please ask a question."
  }else {
  let randnum = Math.random();
   if (randnum < 0.2) {
    answerSpaceEl.innerHTML = " Without a doubt.";
  } else if (randnum < 0.4) {
    answerSpaceEl.innerHTML = " As I see it, yes.";
  } else if (randnum < 0.6) {
    answerSpaceEl.innerHTML = " Concentrate and ask again.";
  } else if (randnum < 0.8) {
    answerSpaceEl.innerHTML = " Don't count on it.";
  } else {
    answerSpaceEl.innerHTML = " Outlook not so good.";
  }
  }
}
```

When there is no input it should say please ask a question but it just skips it and pretends  it doesn't  exist, how do I make this work?

Comment: try `if(!questionEl || questionEl === "")`

Comment: You forgot to get the `value` of `questionEl`   `if(questionEl.value === ""){`

Answer (score 2):

`questionEl` cannot be equal to empty string. I don't know which element you are getting when querying `Question` but it won't be a string. maybe `questionEl.innerHTML` will help or `questionEl.value`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` returns an [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) -- it will likely never be strictly-equal to an empty string. you should probably use `questionEl.value === ""`